# Adding elements and columns based off a cutoff year?

Tags: r

```
structure(list(`2005` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L), `2006` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), `2007` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L), `2008` = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 3L), `2009` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L), `2010` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 0L), `2011` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `2012` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 1L), `2013` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `2014` = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 9L), `2015` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L), `2016` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cutoff = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2005", "2011"
)), .Names = c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", 
"2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "Cutoff"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Given the following dataframe. I would like to add 4 columns to the table.
One column that adds the numbers in the elements before the cutoff year and one column that adds the numbers in the elements after the cutoff year.

Then two more columns where one column adds the total number of years/columns before the cutoff and another column for after the cutoff.

The cutoff years should not be included in the respective rows.

So the final table will end up looking like this:

```
structure(list(`2005` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L), `2006` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), `2007` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L), `2008` = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 3L), `2009` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L), `2010` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 0L), `2011` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `2012` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 1L), `2013` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `2014` = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 9L), `2015` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L), `2016` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cutoff = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2005", "2011"
), Numbers_Before = c(3, 0, 4, 0, 11), Numbers_After = c(1, 0, 
0, 16, 12), Years_Before = c(6, 10, 10, 0, 6), Years_After = c(5, 
1, 1, 11, 5)), .Names = c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", 
"2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "Cutoff", 
"Numbers_Before", "Numbers_After", "Years_Before", "Years_After"
), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` method:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  gather(var, value, `2005`:`2016`) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Numbers_Before = sum(ifelse(var < Cutoff, value, 0)),
         Numbers_After = sum(ifelse(var > Cutoff, value, 0)),
         Years_Before = sum(ifelse(var < Cutoff, 1, 0)),
         Years_After = sum(ifelse(var > Cutoff, 1, 0))) %>%
  spread(var, value) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

**Result:**

```
  Cutoff ID Numbers_Before Numbers_After Years_Before Years_After 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
1   2011  1              3             1            6           5    0    0    1    1    1    0
2   2015  2              0             0           10           1    0    0    0    0    0    0
3   2015  3              4             0           10           1    0    0    1    0    0    0
4   2005  4              0            16            0          11    2    1    0    4    2    5
5   2011  5             11            12            6           5    1    1    3    3    3    0
  2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
1    0    0    1    0    0    0
2    0    0    0    0    0    0
3    0    0    1    2    1    0
4    0    4    0    0    0    0
5    1    1    0    9    2    0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to first use `melt` to put the table in a tidy format then use some data.table operations to tally up the number of years or of the numbers before and after the Cutoff years.

```
library(data.table)

dt = setDT(structure(list(`2005` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L), `2006` = c(0L, 
  0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), `2007` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L), `2008` = c(1L, 
  0L, 0L, 4L, 3L), `2009` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L), `2010` = c(0L, 
  0L, 0L, 5L, 0L), `2011` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `2012` = c(0L, 
  0L, 0L, 4L, 1L), `2013` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `2014` = c(0L, 
  0L, 2L, 0L, 9L), `2015` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L), `2016` = c(0L, 
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cutoff = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2005", "2011"
  )), .Names = c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", 
  "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "Cutoff"), row.names = c(NA, 
  5L), class = "data.frame"))

dt[, row := rownames(dt)]
dt2 = melt(dt, id.vars = c('Cutoff', 'row'), variable.name = 'Year', variable.factor = F)

dt2[, Numbers_Before := ifelse(Year < Cutoff, value, 0)] 
dt2[, Numbers_After := ifelse(Year > Cutoff, value, 0)]
dt2[, Years_Before := ifelse(Year < Cutoff, 1, 0)]
dt2[, Years_After := ifelse(Year > Cutoff, 1, 0)]

dt3 = dt2[, .(Numbers_Before = sum(Numbers_Before), Numbers_After = sum(Numbers_After), 
              Years_Before = sum(Years_Before), Years_After = sum(Years_After)), by = row]

dt = merge(dt,dt3, by = 'row')

> dt
   row 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 Cutoff Numbers_Before Numbers_After Years_Before Years_After
1:   1    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0   2011              3             1            6           5
2:   2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2015              0             0           10           1
3:   3    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    2    1    0   2015              4             0           10           1
4:   4    2    1    0    4    2    5    0    4    0    0    0    0   2005              0            16            0          11
5:   5    1    1    3    3    3    0    1    1    0    9    2    0   2011             11            12            6           5
```

Edit:
Here's using a bit more clever datatable syntax and dcast instead of the ifelses:

```
dt[, row := rownames(dt)]
dt2 = melt(dt, id.vars = c('Cutoff', 'row'), variable.name = 'Year', variable.factor = F)
dt2 = dt2[Year != Cutoff][, .(Numbers = sum(value), Years = .N), by = .(row, Year > Cutoff, Cutoff)]
dt2 = dcast(dt2, row + Cutoff ~ Year, value.var = c('Numbers', 'Years'), fill = 0)
dt = merge(dt, dt2, by = c('row', 'Cutoff'))

> dt
   row Cutoff 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 Numbers_FALSE
1:   1   2011    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0             3
2:   2   2015    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0             0
3:   3   2015    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    2    1    0             4
4:   4   2005    2    1    0    4    2    5    0    4    0    0    0    0             0
5:   5   2011    1    1    3    3    3    0    1    1    0    9    2    0            11
   Numbers_TRUE Years_FALSE Years_TRUE
1:            1           6          5
2:            0          10          1
3:            0          10          1
4:           16           0         11
5:           12           6          5
```